# JS Read Pixel Data of local large image file

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, png, pixel, filereader

I am trying to read the pixel data of a large local file and want to store color information of each pixel as RGBA in a 2D array. Currently I am reading filereader as DataURL. It's taking about 7000ms to read the whole image. My images are usually 5000px x 5000px and of png or bmp format. Can reading as Array Buffer reduce the reading time?

Comment: You may try to use [Java​Script typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) for example `Uint8ClampedArray`. It clamps the values between 0 and 255. This is useful for Canvas data processing.

Comment: Is it possible to convert filereader.result to Uint8ClampedArray for PNG images where reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)?